# Does -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode run on application threads or in GC-dedicated threads?

Tags: garbage-collection, jvm, jvm-hotspot

When reading [Really? iCMS? Really?](https://blogs.oracle.com/jonthecollector/really-icms-really) from this blog, one statement caught my attention:

> The concurrent phases are typically long (think seconds and not milliseconds).
>   If CMS hogged the single hardware thread for several
>   seconds, the application would not execute during those
>   several seconds and would in
>   effect experience a stop-the-world pause.

Which doesn't make sense to me on preemptive operating systems. My assumption is that CMS has one or more collector threads running. Another hypothesis would be that instead of having CMS having dedicated GC threads executing the garbage collection we are talking about making application threads interleave their logic with GC logic (time-multiplexing).

Is this the case? What am I getting wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In HotSpot JVM, the Garbage Collector (including CMS and i-CMS) uses dedicated worker threads.

CMS threads run concurrently with application threads, but they have [higher priority](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/ed8892ef0a8d/src/share/vm/gc_implementation/concurrentMarkSweep/concurrentMarkSweepThread.cpp#l77): `NearMaxPriority`. On a single core machine, CMS cycle could indeed make application threads starving. The idea of CMS incremental mode was to make GC voluntarily yield CPU to the application without relying on OS scheduler.

From [HotSpot GC Tuning Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/cms.html):

> Normally, the CMS collector uses one or more processors during the
>   entire concurrent tracing phase, without voluntarily relinquishing
>   them. Similarly, one processor is used for the entire concurrent sweep
>   phase, again without relinquishing it. This overhead can be too much
>   of a disruption for applications with response time constraints that
>   might otherwise have used the processing cores, particularly when run
>   on systems with just one or two processors. Incremental mode solves
>   this problem by breaking up the concurrent phases into short bursts of
>   activity, which are scheduled to occur midway between minor pauses.

Note that CMS incremental mode [was deprecated](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8003822) long ago in 2012.